# How to extract results with column name in shell from postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, shell

I would like to extract results with title of the column from postgres. I am using shell script to do the same. Please find following code which is giving only result without header.

```
#!/bin/sh
DATABASE=retail
USERNAME=root
HOSTNAME=localhost
export PGPASSWORD=root

psql -h $HOSTNAME -U $USERNAME $DATABASE << EOF
COPY (select name,rollno,mark from student';')

EOF

echo "Hi \n Please find student report " | mutt -a "/tmp/query1.csv" -s " Alert" -- abc_email@gmail.com
```

Comment: use `\copy` not `COPY`, and use `WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER)`. See the manual.

Comment: Can I get manual like please ??

Comment: For information on `\copy` read http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html . For details on usage see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`COPY` statement has option `HEADER`. Use it. Another issue in your example is missing target in `COPY` statement (and other syntax error). From security reasons, it should be `stdout` in this case (I do export of `pg_class` table columns `relname`, and `relpages`):

```
psql -c "COPY pg_class(relname,relpages) TO stdout CSV HEADER" postgres > /tmp/query1.csv
```

With this syntax you will get valid CSV file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I want to use condition and join and all how can  I do with your example